# using check box and arraylist in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have an array list in action class. I want to access this arraylist in my jsp page along with a checkbox. if the checkbox is checked i want to get the associated value of checkbox in another actionclass. how can i do this??

Action class:

```
public class CreateModuleAction extends ActionSupport{
       private List modNameList=new ArrayList();
    private int size;
public String manageModule()
    {

      ManageModule ob=new ManageModule();
      modNameList=ob.selectModule();

      if(modNameList.isEmpty()) {
          addActionError("Module list is empty!!!");
          return ERROR;

        }
      else{
         setSize(modNameList.size());
         return SUCCESS;  
          }

    }
public List getModNameList() {
        return modNameList;
    }

    public void setModNameList(List modNameList) {
        this.modNameList = modNameList;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
```

jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Admin Module Management</title>
    </head>
    <body>
             <div class="main">
            <div class="header"> 
<!--              Page heading-->

               <jsp:include page="/templates/heading.jsp" flush="true"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
<!--                Page menu-->

 <jsp:include page="/templates/menu.jsp" flush="true"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="content">
<!--                page content-->

               <div id="right_top" style="position:absolute; left:900px; top:300px;;">
                   <a href="adminCreateModule.jsp"><img src="../images/add.jpg"/>Add</a>
                   <a href="adminEditModule.jsp"><img src="../images/edit.jpg"/>Edit</a>
                   <a href="adminDeleteModule.jsp"><img src="../images/add.jpg"/>Delete</a>
               </div>
              <s:iterator status="size" value="modNameList">
                  <s:checkbox name="modNameCheck" fieldValue="true" value="modNameList"/>
                  <s:property value="modNameList"/>
              </s:iterator>
              <s:actionerror/>

            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="margin-left: 50%">
<!--                page footer-->

              <jsp:include page="/templates/footer.jsp" flush="true"/> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i will add some code that i have tried

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use struts2 [checkboxlist tag](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/)

```
<s:form action="myAction">
  <s:checkboxlist list="modNameList" name="modNameCheck"/>
</s:form>
```

Now in yoyr `myAction` action class declare

```
private List modNameCheck; //with getter/setter
```

It will have entries which were checked in the jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you want submit values from checkboxes to action then you need `form` in your JSP. If you want to display checked/unchecked checkboxes depending on some values from action then you need some condition check in `value` attribute.

```
<s:checkbox name="modNameCheck" value="list.contains(something)"/>
```